# Very thick text when using svg

Tags: svg

I'm using [mathcha.io](https://www.mathcha.io/) for create some figures. I exported them as svg. If I see on any browser looks perfect.

[image]

But, if I render this svg at tex file, all text if so thick and I can't solve this, I tried to change some properties of the file like stroke-width and others.

[image]

Here is example code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering   
    \includesvg{stackoverflow.svg}
    \caption{Some caption.}
    \label{fig:initialBN}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And [svg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ul703dJijSe9d2XlD98SVYP6vcI-6MvP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Better to include PDF into TeX. Do have the possibility to export to PDF instead of SVG?

Comment: Package `svg` uses Inkscape to convert the given svg file to pdf format, so you have to either edit the stroke width manually with Inkscape or find a way to export to pdf with a reduced stroke width. LaTeX has currently no native support of svg files.

Comment: I will try both options.